# Powershell show headers on second run of a commandlet

Tags: powershell, header

I have a script that should get the last ten event logs from both system and application logs and it works fine but I would like it to show the headers each time get-evetlogs is called as it stands they are only shown once.

```
function EventLogs {
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
$lognames = @("application", "system")
foreach ($name in $lognames) {
    get-eventlog -logname $name -After $date -EntryType Warning |select -first 10
}
}
```

This also happens if I call it outside the loop such as

```
get-eventlog -logname system -After $date -EntryType Error
get-eventlog -logname application -After $date -EntryType Error
```

Is there a way to make it show the headers such as Index and Time each time it is called rather than just at the top of the first run?  Also if you happen to know a correct name for the headers it would help with future google searches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this in ICE and everytime i call eventlogs, it shows me the same info.

Index, Time, EntryType, Source, InstanceID, Message

20 records

What is it exactly you're not seeing?

put this behind your get-eventlog line | Format-Table Index,Time,EntryType,Source,InstanceID,Message

Comment: That is what I'm seeing but I would like to see the headers after the 10th record as it's a new log.

This is probably the clearest example of it missing the headers on a new log.

    $date = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
    get-eventlog -logname application -After $date -EntryType Error |select -first 2
    get-eventlog -logname system -After $date -EntryType Warning |select -first 2

Comment: @nire, this should really be a comment as it doesn't answer the question. However, I concur that I don't see what the issue is here.

Comment: put this behind your get-eventlog line
| Format-Table Index,Time,EntryType,Source,InstanceID,Message

Comment: @nire Thanks that did it just with the select, if you want to edit the first post I will mark as an answer
 
|select -first 2 |Format-Table Index,Time,EntryType,Source,InstanceID,Message